# Multidatespicker theme does not show up

Tags: jquery-multidatespicker

I can't seem to understand why the theme for my MultiDatesPicker is not showing up... can someone please point out what I am missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <h1 id="mdp-title">MultiDatesPicker <span class="mdp-version"></span> for jQuery UI</h1>
            <tr>
                <td>Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <li class='demo'>
                        <div class='box'>
                            <div id="date" class="datepicker" style="display:block;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#date").multiDatesPicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

How embarrassing, I figured out my problem... I forgot to include my CSS...